# Can we leave a pug alone for 9 to 11 hours during the day?

Tags: dogs, pet-selection

We are thinking of getting a Pug but want to know if this breed of dog would be okay left alone during the day.  The dog could be alone for up to 11 hours but usually more like 9 hours.

Answer (score 10):

If you are going to be out for 9-11 hours a day then your sleep time will be around 7-8 hrs a day. It means the dog will be alone for almost 16 to 18 hours. Add the time you will do household chores and ask yourself if you are going to be able to give your dog even 3-4 hours a day, which according to me is very minimal.

So I would request you to not get a dog if you don't have time for it. I own a pug and know how affectionate they are and happy to be with people. They will sleep 12 hours in total but when a pug is awake it wants you awake to play with it.

Comment: please edit your answer,and correct the spelling.

Comment: I've edited your answer to make it read better. As @trondhansen says, a good answer should be written to the best of your ability and answers with better punctuation, grammar and spelling are more likely to be upvoted. Please read [answer] for more tips.

Answer (score 6):

That is a very long time for, especially a puppy, to be left alone. A pug could be fine but I think almost more important than breed is to select the specific puppy who will be ok.

This situation would likely be very stressful for a moderately high energy dog. They require a lot of stimulation and walks. Try to choose a puppy with less energy who will be happy just snoozing until you get home to play!

As with other posters I agree that puppy day care is a great option. Another option is if someone you know, friend or family can check in on your puppy in the day for a quick play session.

Answer (score 4):

11 hours is a long time for a dog to be alone, 9 is OK but the regular 8 hour intervals or less is preferred as they need to pee/poo (unless you litter train him). Dogs are social animals and would want your companionship, they need exercise, training, socialization etc. If your pooch is not entertained or stimulated they have high chances of acquiring behavioral issues such as destruction of your property (boredom), house soiling, anxiety etc.

For the days that you would be gone for 11 hours I would suggest bringing him to doggy daycare, he will get a lot of attention and playtime with other dogs and people.

Answer (score 3):

The fact, that you have decided to ask this question shows that you have doubts about whether this is a suitable arrangement and that you are inclined to be a responsible owner. This is an admirable approach.

As descendants of wolves, dogs (pugs included) are instinctual pack animals. What you are proposing is highly irresponsible and likely will lead to separation anxiety and behavioural problems; with the dog being "destructive" by chewing on furniture, shoes and so forth. You will also force this dog to be able to hold urine for 9-11 hours straight. That's a long time; even during the night when metabolism slows down 11 hours is an absolute maximum a dog can usually hold.

For a more scientific opinion please refer to [***Code of practice for the welfare of dogs***](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/697953/pb13333-cop-dogs-091204.pdf) published by the *Department for Environmental Food & Rural Affairs (UK)* which on page 8 reads:

> Dogs are sociable animals that need, enjoy and value company.
> Consequently, many dogs do not like being left alone and may suffer if
> left without company, or with nothing to do for long periods of time.
> Some dogs become distressed and suffer if they are left on their own,
> even for short periods. **Experts recommend four hours as the maximum
> time period.**

You are not getting this dog to cause him/her distress and stress for yourself but to enjoy this one and unique bond that human beings have been able to form with dogs. However, this doesn't come without effort. As much as some breeds may predisposed to handle loneliness, no dog was designed to be alone for a full day, day after day.

Answer (score 2):

Pugs (and dogs in general) are ... demanding. It could still work as long as you give him extra attention when you get home. Also, as above, I'd recommend a doggy daycare so he won't be lonely and bored

Answer (score 0):

If you have to leave any dog for up to 9 hours on its own please do not get one. I am a pug owner and I know pugs like to be around people playing and socializing. Also 9 hours is a long time for a dog to not be able to relive itself and you will end up having a dog that soils in the house. We got our pug from a man who was an estate agent and was often out of the house for 8 or more hours, we noticed a significant difference in our pug after a few days of not being left alone for hours on end.

Comment: Your answer could be better if you linked to online articles/information about how pugs "deal with long seperation periods". More information comparing the "significant difference" would also be helpful, but be careful that the improvement isn't something that can be attributed to settling in to a new home/environment. btw, Congrats on the new pup. :)

Answer (score -1):

In EU it is illegal to leave dogs alone for more than 5 hours. There is a reason for that. This question is really stupid. Dog's need to take a walk every 3-4 hours, even if it is just around the block for 10 minutes. Would you accept that someone locked the bathroom for ten hours?

Comment: I would be interested in seeing the law you are talking about.  Can you provide a reference?

Comment: The law says something like "adapted to the animal's needs and natural behaviour" (there is no specific law for dogs, it is the same wording for all domesticated animals). The legislation is then combined with provisions from the relevant authority that are specific to different species and situations. Here is a reference (in Swedish) https://www.lycklighund.se/hur-lange-far-jag-lamna-hunden-ensam-hemma/ for dogs.